# How to change directory and execute cscript in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

I am attempting to add printer ports and printers to a local machine via a batch file.
Firstly I need to navigate to C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US folder and then execute the following command

```
Cscript Prnport.vbs -a -r IP_xx.xx.xx.xx -h xx.xx.xx.xx
```

and then add the printer driver and printer via these calls

```
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /ia /m "HP Universal Printing PCl 6" /h "x64" /v "Type 3" /f %windir%\inf\ntprint.inf /u
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /if /b "XXXXXX (HP LaserJet P4515)" /f "%windir%\inf\ntprint.inf" /r "IP_xx.xx.xx.xx" /m "HP Universal Printing PCl 6"
```

How can this be done within a batch file? Thanks in advance!

---

---

Solution found by OP copied into question in convenient form

```
pushd "%windir%\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\"
Cscript Prnport.vbs -a -r IP_xx.xx.xx.xx -h xx.xx.xx.xx 
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /ia /m "HP Universal Printing PCl 6" /h "x64" /v "Type 3" /f %windir%\inf\ntprint.inf /u 
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /if /b "NPI8199E8 (HP LaserJet P4515)" /f "%windir%\inf\ntprint.inf" /r "IP_xx.xx.xx.xx" /m "HP Universal Printing PCl 6"
```

Comment: Add those lines into a batch file, replace your xx.xx.xx.xx with %1 and %2 and when calling the bath file add those ip's as parameters

Comment: Sorry, but after some searching I found the answer I was looking for

    pushd "%windir%\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\
    Cscript Prnport.vbs -a -r IP_xx.xx.xx.xx -h xx.xx.xx.xx

    rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /ia /m "HP Universal Printing PCl 6" /h "x64" /v "Type 3" /f %windir%\inf\ntprint.inf /u
    rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /if /b "NPI8199E8 (HP LaserJet P4515)" /f "%windir%\inf\ntprint.inf" /r "IP_xx.xx.xx.xx" /m "HP Universal Printing PCl 6"